# Can't get first item in array Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I get some seasons of a series from my API.
After that, I want to use `seasons[0]` to get the first item in the array.
The problem is that `seasons[0]` returns `undefined`.

My Code looks like this :

```js
 async ionViewWillEnter() {
    const seasons = await this.serieService.fetchCompleteSerie(this.serie);
    this.seasons = seasons;
    console.log(seasons); //output below
    console.log(seasons[0]); //undefined
    this.selected = seasons[0]; //undefined

  }
```

my service looks like this:

```js
async fetchCompleteSerie(serie: Serie) {
    let allSeasons: any;
    let serieSeasons = [];
    let allEpisodes: any;
    let seasonEpisodes: any;
    allSeasons = await this.http.get('https://www.myapp.com/api/seasons/', this.httpOptions).toPromise();
    await allSeasons.forEach(async season => {
      season["episodes"] = [];
      if (season.serie === serie.url) {
        allEpisodes = await this.http.get('https://www.myapp.com/api/episodes/', this.httpOptions).toPromise();
        allEpisodes.forEach(episode => {
          if (episode.season === season.url) {
            season.episodes.push(episode);
            }
      });
        serieSeasons.push(season);
      }
    });
    return serieSeasons;
  }
```

The console output looks like this :
[image]

Why is it `undefined`?

Comment: This is quite strange.

Comment: I know. First i thought it could be because of the async but I've no idea why

Comment: this happen with me as well when getting data from a signalr hub and trying to push the values into an array, but in my case i am using filter to get the data and the data is being returned

Comment: Do you know how i could filter my array for the first item?

Comment: No, but can you try something like this `await this.serieService.fetchCompleteSerie(this.serie).then(seasons => {this.seasons = seasons});`

Comment: Sounds good. But sadly doesn't work. ```this.seasons[0]``` still returns ```undefined```.

Comment: did you try moving all your logic inside the `then`?

Comment: The issue is caused because the data is not fetched while you try to access the data. you will have to use a callback to wait, or create another await function and put your access code in it for this to work.

Comment: Ok i'll try that. But in the meantime. Can you explain me why the ```console.log(seasons) ```returns me all the data i requested. And after I console logged all the seasons I did ```console.log(seasons[0]) and it returned me undefined

Comment: Trt using a `forEach` and push your season objects into a new array.then try `newArraySeasons[0]`. let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and found something strange. I did the ```forEach``` in the ```then()``` method. I also got rid of the ```async``` and the ```await``` since it didn't work with them. Now I found out that it didn't even go through the ```forEach``` like there wouldn't be any elements in the array. But I console.logged my result and got the full array. What is going on here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `forEach` which DOES NOT RETURN the promises you try to wait for. For that reason `seasons[0]` is still `undefined`. But since you log the array to the console and THE SAME array object is used inside your callback, the console refreshes the output after the data arrives. If you clone the array before logging, you will see that its empty  `console.log([...seasons]);`

Simply switch `forEach` to `map` and use `Promise.all`.

```
  async fetchCompleteSerie(serie: Serie) {
    let allSeasons: any;
    let serieSeasons = [];
    let allEpisodes: any;
    let seasonEpisodes: any;
    allSeasons = await this.http
      .get("https://www.myapp.com/api/seasons/", this.httpOptions)
      .toPromise();
    await Promise.all(allSeasons.map(async season => {
      season["episodes"] = [];
      if (season.serie === serie.url) {
        allEpisodes = await this.http
          .get("https://www.myapp.com/api/episodes/", this.httpOptions)
          .toPromise();
        allEpisodes.forEach(episode => {
          if (episode.season === season.url) {
            season.episodes.push(episode);
          }
        });
        serieSeasons.push(season);
      }
    }));
    return serieSeasons;
  }
```